# how do I use the :valid and :invalid selectors for css?

Tags: html, css

I’m new with coding and I heard from a friend that it’s possible to use the `:valid` and `:invalid` selectors inside my css for my form. But how do I do this?

Comment: Do you mean something like this in the HTML   -   Email: <input type="email" required>   -    And for this you'd like to apply :valid and :invalid?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i mean.
I want to style it for valid but also for invalid in the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually an interesting question. 
I believe it's one of those things that's brand new for CSS3. 
Not sure whether you can already apply it. I don't think you can at this moment, because I just tried it on a fiddle and it wasn't working for me. So probably it's something that is going to be introduced with another update of CSS Selectors.

The way you use it is like this:

html:

```
Email: <input type="email" required>
```

css:

```
input[type=email]:invalid {
  outline: red solid 3px;
}
 
input[type=email]:valid {
  outline: lightgreen solid 3px;
}
```

With the above CSS, the email field will be styled with a red outline even before the user enters anything. Once the user types in a valid email address, the outline will turn green.

Hopes this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the documentation:

- [:valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Avalid)
- [:invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid)